# Set Allowable IP in Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ip, web-config

I want to set IP in web.config in an MVC project that only an specified ip can visit the site, but other ip's see under construction view.
Can anyone tell me how can i do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and `REMOTE_ADDR` ServerVariables to get Client IP Address then match with your permitted list and perform further action based on your condition.

```
   string ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];  
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))  
   {  
     ip = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];  
   }
```